# Change Finder keyboard shortcut for Move 2 Items - MacOS Sonoma

Tags: macos

The default is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

I'd like to change it to  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

In System Settings it appears keyboard shortcut options for Finder are no longer available to edit. Also, the shortcut changes from "Move Item Here" to "Move 2 Items Here" etc depending on item count.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this, but I'm not sure of the wisdom of it.
It's pretty gracessless.

Because the menu item changes depending on item count, you have to add the same key command for all potential numbers…

[image]

Picture from Mojave, but it's the same right up to Ventura. Settings moved to
Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts… > App Shortcuts
I haven't seen Sonoma yet to know if they moved it yet again.

Also note that by default there are no apps listed in the control panel - you have to add them as needed.

Comment: It's in the same place in Sonoma. There's no control panel in MacOS. Maybe you could edit my question again, but goal is to set just one hot key combo, instead of the many/infinate for each 2, 3, 4 items etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, uses [Keybaord Maestro w/ wildcard](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-to-select-a-menu-with-wildcards/22225) "Alternatively, you can start the name with an ^ and use a regular expression to match the menu." Works for 'Move Item' and 'Move 2 Items Here' and all other number of items moving.

[image: Move * Items) Here]

This solution uses KM though, hopefully there's a non third party app solution that can be found also so leaving solution not yet found.